# Getting hex form of escape characters in C

Tags: c, hex

I have a program that takes a string, breaks it up by white space, and then analyzes each part of the string.

When I encounter an escape character, such as single quote: \', I want to print out its hex form: 0x27.

I tried to look up how to do this, but haven't found anything useful. Is there a way to access the hex code of an escape character, or do I have to manually printout the hex codes in print statements?

Comment: But a single quote *isn't* really an escape character. I can understand if you wanted to print unprintable characters using hex, but a perfectly safe and printable single-quote? A single quote only needs to be escaped if inside a character literal (to distinguish it from the opening and closing single quotes of the character literal), but not otherwise. I'm not saying that your question is wrong, but that the example you chose might have been better picked.

Answer (score 3):

If your part of the string is a character, as you say, you can print it like:

```
char = '\'';
printf("caracter: %x", c);
```

A character is just an `int` of 1 byte. The specifier in [printf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) outputs that int in a certain format, such as characters based on [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) (`"%c"`) or as a normal number (`"%d"`) or as a hexadecimal representation of its value (`"%x"`).

Comment: and if you need it as 0x27, then "0x%x"

Comment: @amdixon: better to use `%#x`.